# Can I prevent getJSON requests from running again when returning to page with this code?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm using this code to create do some stuff which include creating links.

I'd like to create a link on the target page (or use the back button) that will allow the user to return to the originating page where this code runs without making the `getJSON` requests again (unless the page is intentionally refreshed).

I want to improve performance which suffers since the `getJSON` requests are made again when the user returns to the originating page. This is especially true in Chrome while I see reasonably good performance in FF as is. (Is it possible that FF is caching but Chrome isn't? How could I test?)

It is fine for the data to expire after some period and force a rerun the requests to refresh the results.

CODE EXAMPLE

```
$.when( $.getJSON(url0), $.getJSON(url1), $.getJSON(url2), $.getJSON(url3),$.getJSON(url4), $.getJSON(url5),$.getJSON(url6) ).done( function() {
    $.each(arguments, function(index, result) {
        var data = result[0];
        utcday =  data[0].createdOn;
        ltrDay = moment.utc(utcday).format("DD MMM YY");


$('#listDiv').append("<div class= \"ellipsis listItemDiv\" ><div class=\"ltrFolder\" ><a title= \"Past Editions of " + nwsltrNames[index] + "\" href = \"" + idString3 + nwsltrID[index] + "\"><i class=\"fa fa-folder-o\"></a></i></div><div id=\"" + data[0].id + "\"class= \"ellipsis listTitle\" style=\"font-size:1.2em;\">" + nwsltrNames2[index] + "<div class= \"ellipsis \"><a style=\"font-size:.8em;\"title= \"" + data[0].conversation + "\" class = \"addressClick\" id =\"" + nwsltrID[index] + "\"><span class =\"point\" ><i class=\"fa fa-newspaper-o\"></i></span>" + data[0].conversation + "</a><div class=\"ltgrey\" style=\"text-transform:uppercase;padding-top:3px;letter-spacing: normal;\">" + ltrDay + "</div></div></div><div class=\"txtHead\" >" + data[0].textHead + "</div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the json in a variable. This will prevent you from having to request the same json again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Any chance you can point me to an example of how to do that with this code?

Comment: These getJSON call are chained so 7 objects are returned. Sorry, I just don't get your proposed approach and how it could be implemented. Any additional info is much appreciated.

Comment: After the chain is resolved for the first time just store all the results in an array. The next time just read it from the array.

Comment: Again, thanks for the suggestion but solving this is above my pay grade without a code example or pointer to one.